# Mongodb, sharding and multiple windows services

Tags: windows-services, mongodb

In order to get sharding to work I need to run two copies of mongod.exe. One as a shard and one as the config server. How can I install both mongod instances as windows services?

Comment: I thought you would be able to do this with the --serviceName  command line option, but even with unique Service Names the Display Name is still "Mongo DB" and there is a clash. This seems to be a bug. See http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1590

Comment: Eliot merged my patch for SERVER-1590 a while back so the lates 1.7.x series has it. Unfortunately, it is likely not to be merged into 1.6.4 or 1.6.5. However, 1.8 (stable) should be released in December.

Answer (score 13):

The following command line will install a 2nd instance of Mongo DB. Note that you have to provide *serviceName*, *serviceDisplayName*, *port*, *dbpath* and *logpath* in order to avoid collisions.

> **mongod** --install --serviceName "*Mongo DB 2nd instance*" --serviceDisplayName "*Mongo DB 2nd instance*" --port 37017 --dbpath *c:\data\db2* --logpath *c:\data\logs\mongolog2.txt*

Then you just start the service with

> net start "*Mongo DB 2nd instance*"

Comment: Error parsing command line: unknown option install
try './mongod --help' for more information.
There is no --install command under mongod.

Answer (score 3):

Use sc.exe from the Windows Resource Kit ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192 ) which allows you to specify an unique display name for each instance:

`sc.exe create "Mongo DB 1" binPath= "c:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --service --dbpath=c:\data\db --logpath=c:\data\log.txt"`

Comment: The problem is that the service and display name need to be unique. This is (was) a bug in mongo.

Answer (score 2):

create a new config file with different port, db location, etc.. and save as mongod2.cfg

```
mongod --install --serviceName 'Mongo DB 2nd instance' --serviceDisplayName 'Mongo DB 2nd instance' -f 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod2.cfg'
```

**need to use full path to the new config file**

this will install as service and you can edit all configurations, like the main instance

Answer (score 1):

Mongo added a --serviceDisplayName flag in 1.8

Comment: --serviceDisplayName doesn't suffice, you will eventually incour in service name and data file collisions