# Is it possible to Set up Master/Slave on the same machine?

Tags: mongodb

I have a question with respect  to Mongo DB Master / Slave setup **on to the same machine** .

I am using Ubutu 12 as OS .
Do i need to have two copies of MongoDB in the same machine ??

If yes , how can it allow to install two  times seperately ??

```
(sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163428/running-multiple-instance-of-mongod-as-service

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437173/mongodb-sharding-and-multiple-windows-services/9273816

Comment: To divert completely from the linked questions, yes it is possible to run more than one mongod on the same machine but it is NOT RECOMMENDED. Instead if you want to use the same machine for two mongods it is recommended to use virtual machines or some other container instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the linked questions are for Windows and this is a Linux command I will divert from the "Possible duplicate" comment.

Yes you can run multiple `mongod`s on the same machine. Instead of installing multiple times you just start `mongod` differently like such:

```
./mongod --dbpath /foo/bar/otherpath --port some_other_port
```

source: https://serverfault.com/questions/296246/multiple-mongos-on-one-server

But it is not recommended to do this due to resource contention, especially for memory. It will be horrid for even a development server and if you intend to put this setup into production then you might as well just go for one `mongod`.

If you want to run multiple instances on the same machine it is instead recommended to use containers such as virtual machines or something else. There are a few out there.

Comment: I'm wondering: How does virtualization help? Doesn't that just add overhead? And doing replication on a single instance is just for testing, IMHO.

Comment: @xeraa Many cloud servers run on virtualisation, AWS/Rackspace etc. It doesn't add anymore overhead than running multiple systems on one machine. If you want to test replication etc, virtualisation is easily the best way to go, setting them up on the same pool of resources in the same space will just make your testing a living nightmare.

Comment: Virtualization without overhead? I'd be sceptical about that, even vendors attribute a performance penalty of a few percent (http://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2012/10/the-virtualization-tax-is-often-greatly-exaggerated.html). And others have found much worse results: http://serverfault.com/a/358040/104131 (even though this might be a little outdated). It is a nice way of separating users / applications, but it's a trade-off. Do you have any references to the virtualization recommendation (especially in the context of MongoDB)? Would be interested in that :-)

Comment: @xeraa I didn't say it wouldn't have overhead, I merely said that most cloud servers are built on that principle and that it will produce much better testing results for this scenario than putting the mongods onto the same server.

Comment: @xeraa I do not have references as to which is best, it is opinionated. I prefer, personally, vmware but many others prefer virtual machine etc.

Comment: @xeraa hmm, realised I haven't made sense when I re-read this thread. VMs can stop hardware contention for one by creating entire containers for mongod's. Each virtual machine would be a machine in itself with it's own self contained resources and management.

Comment: Sure, you can cleanly partition resources. However, you'll need to run multiple instances of your operating system (which might be pretty small if run headless). But this thread's scenario is generally pretty pointless...

Comment: I mean running multiple instances of the same data on a single server. You won' get a lot of redundancy and I wouldn't expect better performance (for reads from secondaries).

Comment: @xeraa Yea that true, it kinda defeats the point in a production envo