# MongoDB instances (Windows)

Tags: windows, mongodb

Can i run more that one instance of MongoDB on one Windows-machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'm running 4 (on different ports) ...

You might be asking can you run more than one SERVICE?

The answer is no (at the moment) at least not the way you are supposed to ...

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Windows+Service

This is supposed to be fixed in the next verision (1.7)

http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1590

However, there are some work-arounds you can use, see here ...

[Mongodb, sharding and multiple windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437173/mongodb-sharding-and-multiple-windows-services)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run more than one service on Windows.

On mongodb 1.8 you have a new option --serviceDisplayName that allow you to run multiple services, of course you have to use different port.

For example :

```
"C:\Mongodb\bin\mongod" --bind_ip your-ip-adress --logpath "C:\data\db\mongo.log" --logappend --dbpath "C:\data\db" --serviceName MongoServiceTest --serviceDisplayName MongoServiceTest --port 27017 --install
```